# Prove symmetric matrix space $\mathcal{R}$ and skew-symmetric matrix space $\mathcal{S}$ have relation $\mathcal{R} = \mathcal{S}^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem**

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ over $\mathbb{R}$, let $\mathcal{S}$ denote the subspace of symmetric matrices, and let $\mathcal{R}$ denote the subspace of skew-symmetric matrices. For matrices $X, Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ define their inner product by $\langle X, Y\rangle=Tr(X^TY)$. Show that, with respect to this inner product, $\mathcal{R} = \mathcal{S}^\perp$

**What I Have Done**

This looks like the generalization of orthogonal complement defined for vector.

According to the definition, I could write $S^\perp = \{V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}: \langle V, A \rangle=Tr(V^TA)=0\}$. I could also write $R = \{B: B = -B^T\}$.

I know I need to prove $\mathcal{R} \subseteq \mathcal{S}^\perp$ and $\mathcal{S}^\perp\subseteq \mathcal{R}$ respectively. However, I do not know how to use the skew-symmetry and symmetry condition in the problem since the trace merely depends the diagonal entries.

I appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Remark that $dim(R)+dim(S)=n^2$. Let $A\in S, B\in R$,  $tr(A^TB)=tr(AB)=tr(B^TA)=-tr(BA)=-tr(AB)$, This implies that $tr(A^TB)=0$ and  and $R$ is the orthogonal subspace of $S$.

Comment: I understand. But why you have to say $dim(\mathcal{R}) + dim(\mathcal{S}) = n^2$  at first, this looks redundant.

Comment: At the same time, I just noticed that your proof could only yield $\mathcal{R} \subseteq \mathcal{S}^\perp$ but not the converse.

Comment: How would one prove the converse then?